# Prove every open subset of closed unit square is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

How shall I make use of the open subset here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any open set $U\subseteq\Bbb R^2$ is a countable union of (open) rectangles, because $\Bbb R^2$ has a countable basis of rectangles with rational endpoints.